# PDF with two expressions

Tags: probability, density-function

When we have a probability density function, $f(x)$ for $a<x<b$, then the mean is $\int_{a}^{b} xf(x) dx$. My question is, what happens when we have different expressions for $f(x)$ within different ranges? For example,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 &   a\leq x < b\\
2x &  b \leq x < d 
\end{cases}$$
How would we find the mean now? 
Would we just do it over the two ranges?

Comment: $\int_a^d xf(x)dx = \int_a^b xf(x)dx + \int_b^d xf(x)dx = \int_a^b x\cdot x^2dx + \int_b^d x\cdot 2x dx$

Comment: @ClementC. actually, it would be $g(x)=x \ f(x)$ where you put $f$

Comment: Ok, you did it before I posted it!

Answer (score 1):

> How would we find the mean now? Would we just do it over the two ranges?

Yes.

To be clear, you sum the integrals of the piecewise function $f$ over the intervals of each piece.   For this piece-wise density,
$$\begin{align}\Bbb E[X]\quad & = \int_a^d x\, f(x)\,\operatorname dx \\[1ex] & = \int_a^b x\,f(x)\operatorname d x+\int_b^d x\,f(x)\operatorname d x\\[1ex] & = \int_a^b x\cdot x^2\,\operatorname d x+\int_b^d x\cdot 2x\,\operatorname d x \\[2ex] & = \tfrac 1 4(b^4-a^4)+\tfrac 2 3 (d^3-b^3)\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks a lot, sorry for the hassle.